# PHP MYSQL: Insert "+" sign in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

when i insert let say:

```
mysql_query("insert into table1 (title) values (\"date + book\")");
```

the "+" sign is converted to a space. so it became "date   book" not "date + book"

what should i do to insert it as it is.
but if i directly query this to MYSQL it accept it as it is..
please clear my confusion.. thanks

```
"UPDATE campus_bookinfo SET categoryid = ".$category.", bookversion = bookversion+1, 
iAmount = \"".str_replace(",","",$price)."\", lectureName = '".$tag."', eStatus = 3 WHERE idx_campus_bookinfo = ".$id_bookinfo;
```

Comment: @Treby: Please post the **original** code.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
mysql_query("insert into table1 (title) values ('date + book')")
```

or if it is a variable:

```
mysql_query("insert into table1 (title) values ('$somevariable')")
```

Comment: i tried this already, but this doesn't work. also i tried \" coz the text is from a php variable so i concat it to the query text